# Two home networks but devices can only connect to one?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router

I have the following setup:

- 1 router w/ modem connected downstairs to the ISP, providing both cable and wi-fi internet to the downstairs.
- 1 router upstairs connected to the downstairs router providing cable and wi-fi to the upstairs. (DHCP disabled on this one)

Both connections have their own name (lets call them DownStairs and UpStairs). Everything works great as long as devices only ever connect to one of them. However, I have some devices which would be a lot more useful if they could connect to both networks.

I can switch which network my devices are connected to as long as I completely make them forget the other one (i.e: an device must unlearn UpStairs before it can connect DownStairs).

I'm wondering why this is a problem and all I can come up with is that somehow having different names (and passwords) for the UpStairs and DownStairs networks is a problem.

Ideally I should be able to smoothly connect to one or the other, even if I have to select them manually from the list.

**Update:** I've reconfigured the upstairs router so that it has the same SSID, security type and password as the downstairs router, following this tutorial http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/3494655/how-set-up-router-as-repeater/

However, the problem persists. Once I get downstairs my devices start trying to reconnect to wifi and are unable to.

Comment: Any reason that you are separating the networks (ie why not make them the same network)?

Comment: Are your devices connecting via WiFi?

Comment: What router are you using? Is your endpoint to provide seamless internet access between the 1st and 2nd floors, i.e. if you go from downstairs to upstairs the internet connection doesn't drop and switches routers appropriately?

Comment: ekaj: Yes, that would be the ideal scenario.

Paul: They are. The routers themselves are connected via ethernet cable to each other. 

Kenneth L: The reason is I have no idea how to make them the same network. Would it be as simple as giving them the same SSID and password?